# Php multidimensional array [matrix] sorting columns

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

If I have a matrix

[3,1,2,4]

[a,b,c,d]

And I need sort first row with usort key. But when I want reorder first array how do column moves at well

So output will be like this in this case described top

[1,2,3,4]

[b,c,a,d]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php):

```
$x = [[3,1,2,4],['a','b','c','d']];
array_multisort($x[0], $x[1]);

var_dump($x);
```

Output:

> ```
> array(2) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(4) {
>     [0]=>
>     int(1)
>     [1]=>
>     int(2)
>     [2]=>
>     int(3)
>     [3]=>
>     int(4)
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   array(4) {
>     [0]=>
>     string(1) "b"
>     [1]=>
>     string(1) "c"
>     [2]=>
>     string(1) "a"
>     [3]=>
>     string(1) "d"
>   }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

Comment: ksort is when you have key value relation, but in this case i have 2 separate [value] arrays when I move one array, second array will have to move with first

Comment: Oh I see, in that case you'd want [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)